# Simple Hangman game

Tags: php

Hello to all i am still new to all of this and i would like someones hlp to finish this simple code. I am missing sessions so my guessed letters stay and some simple counter to show nuber of trys left. Ty in advanced.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Pogodi rijec!</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
session_start();
$str = strtolower("Avion");
$arr1 = str_split($str);
$brojslova = count($arr1);
$slovo = $_POST["slovo"];
$skrivenoPolje = array();


for ($i=0; $i < $brojslova; $i++) { 
$skrivenoPolje[$i] = "_";

for ($j=0; $j < $brojslova; $j++) {

if ($slovo == $arr1[$j]) { 
    $skrivenoPolje[$j] = $slovo;
}

}}
print_r($skrivenoPolje);
print_r($arr1);
print_r($brojslova);
?>
<form action="vjesala.php" method="POST">
<p>Unesi slovo</p>
<input type="text" name="slovo">
<input type="submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This comment doesn't directly contribute to a solution, but PHP is not the language to be using for these types of game. I would recommend using java script.

Comment: @Oisin PHP is perfectly fine for building a Hangman game

Comment: @Gordon I may be wrong, but with PHP you have to deal with the page refreshing on every move (unless you use ajax or something similar)

Comment: @Oisin refreshing is not a problem. Hangman is a turn based game. You guess a character by submitting a POST request to the server. The webserver sends the updated response. That's all there is to it.